# Android Listview Design Pattern with diff colors in alternate pattern positions

Tags: android, listview

I am stuck with a ListView design in android, I need to design a listview in android as a pattern which is like 0,2,5,9,14,20th... positions with the same colors and rest all with same color.

[image]

Comment: You just make the getView method of the adapter set the background... You have to figure out the number pattern, though

Comment: yes cricket that pattern is my need using the getview and set background is what i can do but how to track that number pattern?

Comment: Is there any logic behind choosing these positions or they are random? If there are only six places in which u want to have the same background then u can use 'if else' inside your getView method of your adapter. Other wise you need to figure out the pattern.

Comment: No the positions are not random , items can be dynamics but the pattern is like the above screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

in your getView method:

```
if (checkPosition(position)) {
   //set your color
}
```

and your checkPosition method:

```
private boolean checkPosition(int position) {
    return checkPosition(0, 2, position);
}

private boolean checkPosition(int compare, int step, int position) {
  return position == compare || (position < compare && checkPosition(compare + step, step++, position));
}
```

If I understood your patter correct, it should works.

Comment: thanks, it seems to do something but not the appropriate. Can you improve your answer its not updating the list in proper pattern.